# COCOS JS touch listener

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

i want to add a single touch listener for a cocos layer, this listener should respond any child (Widgets e.g. button, menuItem) that are added to layer. Like in html v can attach listener to complete document object. 
I have added a listener to layer(below) but doesnt works when clicked on widgets.

```
     cc.eventManager.addListener({
        event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
        swallowTouches: true,
        onTouchBegan: function (touch, event){    
            var target = event.getCurrentTarget(); 

        }
    } , this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every object that it is a ccui.Widget or inherits from it has a setSwallowTouches(enable) that lets you choose if a widget will well swallow a touch and it will get or not to its parent. I think if you set every gadget to false it will work just as you want.

Reference: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.8/symbols/ccui.Widget.html#setSwallowTouches